# React Native - I18Next with react-navigation and typescript

Tags: react-native, react-redux, i18next, react-i18next

I have this RN project I started. I need localization in it, and I tried numerous solution for it. I18Next looks like it could really well suit my needs. I'm not sure how to define it in its own file and call it in App.tsx. I used a `useEffect` but I doubt it's wise - even more without any dependencies. Here is what I tried :

i18n.ts:

```js
import i18next from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';
import * as Localization from 'expo-localization';
import en from './en.json';
import fr from './fr.json';

const resources = {en: { translation: en }, fr: { translation: fr }};

i18next
  // .use(languageDetector)
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init({
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    debug: true,
    resources,
    lng: Localization.locale.slice(0, 2),
  });

export default i18next;
```

And the code in App.tsx:

```js
// ...
import i18next from './src/locales/i18n';

export default function App(): React.ReactElement {
  useEffect(() => {
    i18next
      .init()
      .then(() => {
        // TODO - dispatch to redux when this is ready
      })
      .catch(error => console.warn(error));
  });

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate loading={<SplashScreen />} persistor={persistor}>
        <StatusBar hidden />
        <MainNavigation />
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

I get a warning `i18next: init: i18next is already initialized. You should call init just once!`. Indeed, I'm calling `.init()` twice - in the main file and again in the useEffect. But I don't see how to do it otherwise.

Also, is my `useEffect` alright?

[EDIT] I found https://react.i18next.com/latest/i18nextprovider in the doc and using it and deleting the useEffect, the warning is gone - although I'm not sure if it's a good idea since the docs states `You will only need to use the provider in scenarios for SSR (ServerSideRendering) or if you need to support multiple i18next instances - eg. if you provide a component library.`

Comment: according to similar library [docs](https://react.i18next.com/latest/using-with-hooks), you have to import your ```i18n.ts``` in your index files, and that's how i did it in my project. Have you tried it?

Comment: @Oleksii there is no index file in an Expo app, it's all based around App.tsx :)

Comment: oh, okey, then just import it in your App.tsx the way the docs say. Should be imported in your app entry-point file.

Comment: Yes I tried, but if I remove the init in the useEffect, the language selection doesn't work and the `changeLanguage` throws an error.

Comment: Edited the question with more informations

Comment: idk, maybe you can create and MRE cuz i've tried to recreate it myself, and i couldn't, [see here](https://snack.expo.io/@shevchenko27/gnarly-raisins), maybe i did something wrong... my example is not with ts though, but since you are getting an error, does it matter?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I just needed to init it once indeed, and didn't need to use the provider either. Finally nailed it like this:

```js
const onBeforeLift = async () => {
  await initI18Next();
};

export default function App(): React.ReactElement {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate
        loading={<SplashScreen />}
        persistor={persistor}
        onBeforeLift={onBeforeLift}
      >
        <StatusBar hidden />
        <MainNavigation />
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

And in `i18n.ts`:

```js
const resources = {
  en: { translation: en },
  fr: { translation: fr },
  he: { translation: he },
};

export const init = () => {
  const lng = store.getState().user.language
    ? store.getState().user.language
    : Localization.locale.slice(0, 2);

  return (
    i18next
      .use(initReactI18next)
      .init({
        fallbackLng: 'en',
        debug: true,
        resources,
        lng,
      })
  );
};

export default i18next;
```